# Alienware 13 R3 - laptop shuts down without warning under heavy load ONLY when on battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, shutdown, benchmarking

I've been an AW13R3 owner for almost 2 years, i bought a used model without warranty in order to have something to bring with me during job travels.
For a year or so the laptop has been performing greatly, both with AC and battery mode.
However, in the last 3 months or so i've been experiencing some weird issues with it.
Basically, when i play with it on battery, when the laptop goes under heavy load (eg recent games like BFV), the laptop first drops FPS dramatically, then shuts off without warning.
Do note, that i changed the battery when i bought it because it had a 55% wear, and repasted both CPU and GPU 1 month ago.
This issue does not appear while plugged on AC, as the laptop reaches high temps and still works like a charm.
I tried benchmarking the laptop many times, the problem is always the same: while on AC it does not shut off, on battery it first loses FPS, then shuts off, giving a loud bip of static sound. I might guess this could be battery related (battery not giving enough power) or the battery connector being bad. I tried changing power schemes; resetting them (as AW only had 1 OLED power scheme by default); tried a fresh install; unplugged the battery cable and held the power button for 30 seconds to draw off the static, but none of this seems to work.

If anyone has a solution, please let me know. It is a laptop that i hold dearly, it'd be a shame for it to have this permanent issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i bought a used model   ....   almost 2 years [ago]  ..... It probably needs a new battery.

Comment: Impossible, the battery still holds full capacity, it cannot be that.

Comment: It may not hold charge for very long. Older batteries can charge to full and then deplete quickly. Make sure nothing important is running, charge to full, and see how long the battery lasts. Try that.

Comment: I tried that already. The battery lasts around 4 hours running without anything in the background. The issue is not the battery holding charge, the issue is the laptop shutting itself off while doing heavy tasks. After that when i turn it back on the battery still has juice left, it does not deplete itself.

Comment: Thank you. That is better clarity.  Two things at this point. (1) Run Memtest86 (several passes) as a memory fault could cause this (seen it before).  (2) Consider a root kit virus . Try TDSSKiller (Kaspersky)

Comment: This behavior is definitely the battery not a virus.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the battery is holding charge as the OP says, then there can be other causes.  This issue may be battery but not "definitely" the battery as I have seen other causes..

Comment: I did try and use different ram, switched ram slots with them, did not solve anything, and by leaving 8gb of ram instead of 16 it seemed to make matters worse, games wouldn't even boot up and the pc would shut down. And i repeat, this ONLY happens with battery mode, on AC it has zero issues. Don't know about a rootkit virus tho.

Comment: (A) As both ramhound and I noted, it could be battery, especially if not the memory. (B) Root Kit virus is just a suggestion at this point.

Comment: Could a used battery cause to lose power and not give enough energy for the laptop to work under load?? Because despite the battery being more than 1 year old i never used the laptop too frequently, only in occasions when i travel for work, basically 2-3 times per month, not even a daily extensive use.

Comment: **Idea**: Battery level detection giving a false indication of battery exhausted, so shutting down due to "low battery". Note; intermittent false detection, due to heat. A reboot appears to remedy the problem for the moment.